# Ace Editor and entity encoding/decoding

Tags: javascript, editor, ace-editor

I have searched across entire SO. for similar or exact topic and I couldn't find *(or didn't saw) topic on issue that's bothering me. If this is duplicate, and solution already exists, accept my apologies.

Currently I am working on cms application that uses both codemirror and ace editor, either this one or that one, and that depends on user/operator preference which one is going to be fired up once when particular document is loaded.

With codemirror, I have no issues at all. Everything works as expected. Codemirror is loading files via php's file_get_contents() directly into textarea, while ace is loading contents via ajax (current application nature demands so) and the issue that bothers me is actually one single operator/character which is : **&**

I have checked all the methods I wrote in the backend and there is no a single sanitize method or function or preg or whatever.. which I implemented.

The only thing being sanitized by me personally, on backend side is textarea tag, which is being wrapped within comment, and unwrapped again upon saving to file as php/html.

Ace is -aggressively- converting **&** character to **&amp;** entity all the time, no matter what I try, no matter which selected "mode" is chosen (HTML,CSS,PHP, JS... you name it) and I don't want such behavior, I want loaded code to remain intact, on doc/file load/open and doc/file save/write, unless, normally, user doesn't edit or convert those characters manually by hand while editing.

In fact, **<** and **>** are "doing fine" .. ace is not "afraid of 'em", there is no automatic conversion to **&lt;** and to **&gt;** - just **&**.

I spent a lot of time on ace api pages, and found nothing (or didn't looked very good), no particular "setThisThat.option: boolean", etc.. that could solve this little issue.

If that matters, I am using ace **min-noconflict** (modes and themes as well, minified) version 5 days old since this very day.

I know that automatic conversion of "problematic characters" is there for a reason, but I actually do know how to handle those by my self with php, and all I need is to totally disable that feature.

I hope that I was clear regarding my issue, 
here is an issue example with JavaScript mode:

**Expected result**

```
if (typeof(pureTextReal) === "object" && aceSetMode === 'php' ) { /* Code */ }
```

**Ace result**

```
if (typeof(pureTextReal) === "object" &amp;&amp; aceSetMode === 'php' ) { /* Code */ }
```

Comment: tl;dr - I recommend you organize your post to encourage people to read everything. For example, add headings. Make your post pretty.  Maybe even add a summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question should remain open no longer as I accomplished what I wanted.

When the content is loaded with all applicable characters substituted with their html entites and placed inside hidden textarea first, than, textarea.value passed to ace element, upon ace loading, all characters are displayed correctly. Both ace and codemirror are now working exactly the same.

Here is an example of working ace scenario.

**HTML generated via PHP**

Somewhere in the middle of the page, within form ..

> Ace pre tag here, (**either pre or div tag, both are working well**)
>   Note that there is no & present, but nonetheless, it is converted now for good as all other specialcharacters once when it is present

```
    <!-- class cloak hides the element from being displayed -->
    <div id="code-wrapper" style="display: block;">
    <pre id="editor"></pre>
    <textarea id="code-content" name="code-content" class="cloak">
    &lt;h1&gt; Heading for &quot;Page&quot; &lt;/h1&gt;
        &lt;dl class=&quot;currentProject&quot;&gt;
            &lt;dt&gt;Current page ..&lt;/dt&gt;
            &lt;dd&gt;.. is under construction.&lt;/dd&gt;
        &lt;/dl&gt;
    </textarea>
    </div>
```

.. than, right before closing `</body>` tag

> Ace requests, entire JAVASCRIPT in fact is created here, at the bottom of the documents

```
    <div class="cloak">
    <!-- Dynamic PHP generated paths -->
    <script type="text/javascript">var ui={u:'/path/to/library/', i:'/path/to/style/'};</script>

    <!-- Little framework --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/dBmb.js" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> // Dynamic values/elements
        var aceCode = 'editor', aceTHEME = 'dawn', aceSetMode = "php", hidden = 'code-content';

        // Append ace call to head
        dBmb.headScript(ui.u + 'ace/ace.js', true);

        // Append ace-config call to head
        dBmb.headScript(ui.u + 'dbmb.ace.config.js', true);
    </script>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

> portion of linked css stylesheet

```
    div#code-wrapper {
        height: 100% !important;
        padding-top: 5px;
        border-top: 3px solid LightGrey;
    }

    div#code-wrapper * {
        transition: none !important;
    }

    pre#editor {
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        text-align: initial;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }

    .ace_editor {
        font-size: 100% !important;
    }

    .cloak {
        display: none !important;
        max-width: 0 !important;
        max-height: 0 !important;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -10;
        overflow: hidden;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

**Ace custom config**

> This file is previously pulled (created) by custom `dBmb.headScript` function
>   *(appends script tag to the head), at the end of the loaded html document,
>   and it is dynamic. What PHP serves, this script accepts.

```
    // dbmb.ace.config.js
    var wh, textarea, elementAce, safetext, editor;

    document.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {

            elementAce = document.getElementById(aceCode);
            textarea = document.getElementById(hidden);

            editor = ace.edit(elementAce);
            safetext = textarea.value;

            editor.setOptions({
                useWorker: false,
                showPrintMargin: false,
                behavioursEnabled: true,
                theme: "ace/theme/" + aceTHEME,
                mode: "ace/mode/" + aceSetMode
            });

            editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;
            editor.session.setUseWrapMode(true);
            editor.session.setValue(safetext);

            var autoHeight = function() {
                wh = (window.innerHeight - 100);
                elementAce.style.height = wh + 'px';
                editor.resize();
            };

            window.onresize = autoHeight;

            editor.getSession().on('change', function(e) {
                textarea.value = editor.session.getValue();
            }); autoHeight();

    }};
```

After everything is loaded, this is what I get on screen.

[image: Ace Result]

No console notices and errors on anything undefined.

And when **POST** request is altered - `$_POST['code-content']` is what I save to new/edited file.

Comment: So you have proper escaping for textarea in your code, but you don't know where

Comment: No. I do know exactly how my code works, and _I didn't had escaping at all_ except <textarea> tag in both codemirror and ace, where codemirror just worked, and ace didn't wanted to work *(I already described), now, I am writing/injecting escaped code str_replace(array($normalchars), array($substitute), $code) with php first, into hidden textarea, for ace as well, and than passing textarea.value to ace session upon loading. That's huge difference.

Comment: Ace itself doesn't escape anything, if you are calling `editor.setValue("&")` it can't change value to `&amp;` Try adding console.log before setValue to see this

Comment: I have no doubts in Your experience with ace, but trust me, I didn't converted anything on my own, when &amp; appeared in ace - no matter what. And everything, literally everthing, every single bit in my own code is pure UTF-8. So, ace (in my case) did just that. From & to &amp; - on "it's" own. 
However, I don't find that as a flaw, what I tried first was maybe, inapropriate for ace it self (loading content with ajax on the fly, during page load into ace editor element).. Now, it is different. No ajax requests - works.

Comment: Sorry the tone of my first comment was wrong, what i wanted to say is that loading text with ajax requests is the correct way and passing it through textarea is slow and normally shouldn't be done. It would be good to find the root cause of this issue. Were you using setValue or some other call, what happens when you run editor.setValue("&") in the console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74859/discussion-between-spooky-and-a-user).